# Guice - Dynamically selecting provider based on external parameter

Tags: groovy, guice

In guice, Is there a way to select particular implementation for binding based on some external parameter

Eg:

```
public interface Service {
  void sendMessage()
}

class EmailService implements Service {

  public EmailService() { }

  @Override 
  void sendMessage() {
   println "Sending email..."
  }
}

class SMSService implements Service {

  public EmailService() { }

  @Override 
  void sendMessage() {
   println "Sending sms..."
  }
}

class Client {

 private Service service

 @Inject
 Client(Service service) {
     this.service = service
 }

 public void send() {
     service.sendMessage()
 } 
}

public class ServiceProvider implements Provider<Service> {

  Service get() {
      return new SMSService()  //Select implementation here?
  } 

}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
 @Override 
 protected void configure() {

     bind(Service.class).toProvider(ServiceProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON)

 }    
}


public static void main(String...args) {

    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule())
    Client c = injector.getInstance(Client.class)
    c.send()

}
```

In the above example, I'm forced to select which provider to use in Provider get() method. If I want to make this  more dynamic, say for example, based on user preference, is there a way to wait select the provider at runtime and have guice inject it?

Comment: I would not do that with injection. You can inject all the services into client and then do regular if / else logic to select the one you're going to use. You otherwise create an ugly dependency on the injector.

Comment: Binding all implementations seems to be a good idea. The condition for if-else logic mentioned may be passed via system property e.g.

Answer (score 3):

For these kind of problems, guice offers the [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html):

```
 public class SnacksModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure() {
     MapBinder<String, Snack> mapbinder
         = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, Snack.class);
     mapbinder.addBinding("twix").toInstance(new Twix());
     mapbinder.addBinding("snickers").toProvider(SnickersProvider.class);
     mapbinder.addBinding("skittles").to(Skittles.class);
   }
}
```

With this binding, a Map can now be injected:

```
class SnackMachine {
   @Inject
   public SnackMachine(Map<String, Snack> snacks) { ... }
}
```

You can define all your services in advance, and than pick the concrete instance (or provider) from the map byconfigured value.